# Saving EXTREME huge texts in MySQL

Tags: mysql, text

this is an experimental question.
I am currently testing how to work with large data.

My situation (is extreme, I know!):
Let's say I have a string with 10 million chars.
What would be the most effective way to save this in an database?
Thanks!

Comment: depends on the character encoding, but you medium sized text will most likely fit in a mediumtext column which can hold up to 16,777,215 bytes. So nothing extreme here

Comment: @e4c5 TEXT won't be enough, it's up to 64KiB only

Comment: silly me @baao you are right

Comment: Well, at least you were right with the 10Mb is nothing statement... :-) @e4c5

Comment: Is it just text or binary as-well? Although not easy searchable, for just storage you can easily compress text. Which would reduce the data significantly.

Comment: BTW you should explain "effective". Like Size? Performance? Search ability?

Comment: I have tested it with "longtext" but the text does not save. Do you maybe know why? When I echo my current experiment (1 million chars) it works and even really fast but it does not save into the database. I do not get any errors. How to solve this? :D

Comment: And @Rogier for me effective just means that I want to see how I can keep up a good performance (fast page load but also fast work with much requests/data) in my application. Currently it's just experimental :)

Comment: Ok I have now successfully ended my test. I have inserted a row with the maximum of 45 million chars (wow!). After the end of the counting of the chars my browser and also my texteditor crashed :D. And that was not even the finish. The MySQL server only crashed because of the maximum execution time of 30 seconds. But I do not continue or expand this test. Thank you all for your answers, I was successful!